# Сохранить прокрутку при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, localstorage

На одной странице сайта необходимо, чтобы при обновлении страницы пользователю показывалась та часть странице, где он находился. Т.е. если он прокрутил вниз и обновил страницу, то автоматически он остался внизу. Предполагаю, что это делается с помощью `localStorage`, но пока не понимаю как именно. Информацию в интернете найти не смог, странно.

На странице не просто текст, но и `div`, `img`.. мало ли это важно..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let cords = ['scrollX','scrollY'];
// Перед закрытием записываем в локалсторадж window.scrollX и window.scrollY как scrollX и scrollY
window.addEventListener('unload', e => cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]));
// Прокручиваем страницу к scrollX и scrollY из localStorage (либо 0,0 если там еще ничего нет)
window.scroll(...cords.map(cord => localStorage[cord]));
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть пояснили, что код делает =) А то очень много ES6 с которым еще не все умеют работать

Comment: Хотя решение хорошее

Comment: @alexoander добавил комментарии. Уже ES8 на носу

Comment: не забываем про legacy и вообще незачем гнаться впереди хвоста. Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var s= $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(s );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div><div>12</div><div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>12</div>
```

Можно использовать `scrollTop()` для хранения позиции прокрутки. Это значение можно сохранить в `localStorage` , а потом скормить этой же функции, чтобы перейти на это значение на странице. Одно но - для такого перехода необходимо,чтобы весь DOM был уже построен и нарисован иначе будут ошибки.

Comment: А если прокрутка горизонтальная?

Comment: @Darth По аналогии с scrollLeft();